# Ubuntu freezes at "show applications" page

Tags: 20.04, freeze

As a Linux beginner, I installed ubuntu today (no dual boot) with suggested extras.

I come across with few freezes. They happened in the "show applications" place. You know like.. 9 small dots icon that shows all applications when clicked. When I click on groups (that holds similar applications together in one icon) and when I close that group. It re-renders itself again (that's normal).

But sometimes, right after closing the group. Screen freezes. Like. The application menu is open but there is no application loaded to the list yet. Sometimes I can move my mouse but can't click anything.

[Picture of Frozen screen right after closing one of my applications folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKxnF.jpg).
as you can see it froze while loading the applications again

Well, I did search a bit. Ppl suggested accessing a terminal and killing all processes. I tried `Ctrl + Alt + F1` and it sent me to the account signing place (i guess it's for protection) when I type my password and hit enter. the screen goes black. I can press Ctrl+alt+f1 again to do the same thing but the result is also the same black screen instead of the console.

Any possible solution for this problem?

these are few command ppl asked for:

```
>>sudo ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions

ls: cannot access '/home/sayochi/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory
```

```
>>sudo ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions

total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Şub  9 21:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Haz 13 18:57 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Şub  9 21:49 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Haz 13 19:09 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Şub  9 21:49 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Comment: 14.04 is real old... and I don't believe that we still support it. However, in `terminal`, show me `free -h` and `swapon -s`.

Comment: forgive me i didnt specify my version and tagged the wrong version. forum suggested me 14.04 and i assumed that its the latest LTS release without thinking (I removed the tag). my ubuntu is 20.04.2 LTS. and this is the outputs of command @heynnema asked for: [results picture](https://pasteboard.co/K6usrzZ.png)

Comment: Also, [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1345664/edit) and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2G /swapfile is too small, so we'll increase it to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Update #1:**

Update to the latest Nvidia driver 465.31, which can be dowloaded [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/).

[image]

Comment: after reboot, I confirmed what i did and problem still occurs after few trys. I also edited my question as you asked for

Comment: @RtSayochiKun What video card? What driver version? Have you installed any themes?

Comment: I have Intel UHD Graphics 620 and GeForce MX130 shown in terminal. I wasnt using any "theme" before posting this question. but I had "gnome-tweaks" application installed (I still have). i came across plenty of _window rendering_ glitches of gnome-tweaks application. you think this may also causing my problem?

Comment: @RtSayochiKun Does the problem occur when using the Intel or Nvidia video? See Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: I opened and closed different groups like 50 times and no freezing. I think updating my nvidia driver to 465.xx fixed the problem! Thank you!